# How to open port with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, websocket, port, ratchet

Trying to test the Ratchet WS server thing: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

I run the php script, but if I try to connect I get:

```
telnet localhost 24320
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

24320 is the port on which IOServer is set to run. I'm running these commands from the same computer on which the server is running

Tried to connect with javascript too (`ws://mysite.com:24320`), but fails as well.

Do I have to open that port or what? How can I do it?

Comment: you have to allow incoming connections on port `24320`. you have to set this rule on your `iptables` or `firewall`. In Linux, run this command: `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 24320 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: tks it works now :D why dont you post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allow incoming connections on port 24320:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 24320 -j ACCEPT
```